# BSoD - Memory Dump - 0X0000007F

Tags: windows-xp, memory, bsod, hp-elitebook, dump

I have a HP Elitebook 8440P imaged with our Corporate standard image. This image works on any other laptops but not with my 2 laptops.

Windows boots correctly and I get to the login screen. There, I wait for 5-10 seconds before loging in but as soon as I close the lid (Again for 5-10 seconds) and reopen it, I get the BSoD `(Memory Dump - 0X0000007F)`

I disabled the DEP (Data Execution Prevention) in the BIOS.

Specs: CPU: i5 - 4go ram - 250go HDD (Bios updated, Chipset Updated, Video driver updated)

Is there a hotfix for that?

Regards,

David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to update the Video driver released by HP few times later... This has fixed the issue.